# Is there a way to create an organization-wide email address when creating a new user?

Tags: apex, email, administration

Is there a way to create an organization-wide email address when creating a new user?
I tried this in apex but it gave me an error: DML operation Insert not allowed on OrgWideEmailAddress

```
OrgWideEmailAddress owea = new OrgWideEmailAddress(); 
owea.Address = 'test@test.com';
owea.DisplayName = 'test';
insert owea;
```

Comment: I don't think DML for OrgWideEmailAddress is allowed in apex, however you can try using flow as a workaround mentioned under comments(https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdYZfUAN/allow-dml-for-orgwideemailaddress-emailservicesfunctio-and-emailservicesaddress).